# Let's Encrypt Cron job for Azure Scalesets

Tags: azure, cron, lets-encrypt

So, i have a scale set on Azure with VM's that will turn themselves on and off as needs arise. I would like to know if there's a way to automate the process of installing and replicating the same domain certificate in all the web servers, plus, a script to run the cron in all machines without having to go through each manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable auto scale set?

If yes, you should prepare an new image with new domain certificate, then follow this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set) to upgrade it with new image.

If no, you can just update it manually, or use `vmss extension` to update VMSS instances.